# jQuery $.extend results in first object completely replaced by second

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I cannot find a method to demonstrate this other than pure code (no fiddle) but here is what is happening: I make an AJAX get to a JSON file. I save the data to a variable. Once that is done, I make another get to another JSON file, with the intention of combining both data sets.

```
$.get('1.json', function (foo) {
    var res1 = foo;
    $.get('2.json', function (bar) {
        var res2 = bar;
        $.extend(res1, res2);
    });    
});
```

No matter what I do, res1 will output the dataset of res2. I've tried using

```
var baz = $.extend({}, res1, res2);
```

with no luck.

Comment: Have you tried with the first parameter as `true` to signify a deep extend? `.extend(true, res1, res2);`

Comment: Oh, yes that worked. Reading the docs http://api.jquery.com/jquery.extend/ the first example shows that it would merge the two without using deep. Kinda confused.

Comment: Non-deep may confuse since a "shallow copy" destination can "look" deep at casual inspection if "first level (shallow)" properties are deep like "a : { deeper:true }". The "shallow" copied destination res1 from res2 would show "res1.a.deeper", but the "deeper" is not a copy, only "a" was copied.  Inspecting res1 would "appear" to be a deep copy of res2, but in fact only the first level was a copy/merged; deeper is just a side-effect "peek" into res2. Change res2.a.deeper, and res1.a.deeper reflects that. Not understanding this can be a dangerous implication reflected in "Kinda confusion".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, [`.extend`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.extend/) will only do a shallow copy. For example:

```
var obj1 = { 
    a : {
        banana: true
    }
}

var obj2 = { 
    a : {
        monkey: true
    }
}

var obj3 = $.extend({}, obj1, obj2);
/*
    obj3 = {
        a : {
            monkey: true
        }
    }
*/
```

In order to do a deep copy (and to keep your banana), you can use the 2nd signature of `.extend` and pass `true` as the first argument:

```
var obj3 = $.extend(true, {}, obj1, obj2);
```

Comment: To help others: Stryner's solution is correct and works well, but also introduces a new object "{}" into which the others are merged, which is not required, and thus may confuse the precise solution. The simpler original code modified to $.extends(true,obj1,obj2) does work, with obj1 being "extended" - creating a new object is not required for the solution. It is the parameter "true" (for deep copy), as Stryner notes, which is key here. The new object probably came from the speculation in the question, which had strayed off topic.

Comment: @CrisMooney Thanks for adding clarification